# How to pick up color particles from a photo by imageJ?

Tags: imagej

[image]I am doing sediment analysis recently and want to apply imageJ to help me count the tracer particles from normal sand. I have a photo and now want to learn how to count the pink color sand particles and get a percentage from the total particles.

I have read through the color process protocol of imageJ but still no idea how to do it. I will be greatly appreciate if you can show me how to do it. I am totally new to imageJ.

Comment: Hello, please take a look at the information in the imagej tag (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagej) and post this question on the forum instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just some recommendations:

1. I hope you don't use a smart-phone camera. They use opaque processing that gives nice images but not images that are suited for scientific analyses, especially regarding colour.
2. Never ever use JPG-compressed images that show artifacts that can't be removed.
3. You may use colour-thresholding or even colour-deconvolution.
4. Less universal (but perhaps sufficient) is changing the colour-space. I used "RGB to CMYK" which may give a reasonable separation of the pink particles in the magenta channel.
   [image]